# VBA References Not Saving

Tags: excel, database, vba, ms-access, reference

When attempting to open a database file through Access 2016, I'm immediately brought to VBA with a compile error: user-defined type not defined. I've rooted the problem to references not being selected (specifically, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library and similar ones for Word, Office, etc.). I tried to go in, select the references to use them, save the file and try opening it again. However, I'm still brought back to the same error and the references I just selected all are unchecked again.

Does anyone know what could be causeing the references to reset and how to stop them from doing so? My co-workers running the same database file have them selected by default when they run it, but I just installed Access so that might be contributing to the issue. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try adding the missing reference, then compact & repair the database, which might get Access to re-generate the p-code for the VBA project; save & reopen. Fixed?

Comment: Alternatively, you could late-bind all the references, although doing this might introduce bugs if not done carefully (especially without `Option Explicit` specified), and if the project is rather large then it can mean quite a lot of work.

Comment: Compact & repair gives the same error.

Comment: Mathieu I also have     Option Explicit     specified at the top of the function. The project is quite large.

Comment: You might have to write some code to add the GUID of the reference for your co-workers.  You can't really toggle access to trust the VBA model for them though . .. . Is this what you are wanting to do, add the references through VBA?

Comment: Co-workers are using the same version of Access as me (2016). And all I'm wanting to do is have those references enabled by default throughout the entire code or make them default for VBA in general. I'm not the one who wrote the code, and I'm not very proficient with VBA so sorry about the lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the database without any of the onload options and making the necessary changes, then save, close, reopen.  To open without additional criteria in Access just open the file while holding the shift key.

i.e. shift + double click the file

Comment: So when I open it using shift+double click, the references are saved from when I added them before. However, when I save, close, and reopen normally they're all unchecked again.

Comment: Hmm, it is possible to set references programmatically as well.  Perhaps something in there is resetting them.  Can you post the VBA code from the database in question?

Comment: Just looked and saw that you've stated the project is very large.  Perhaps just anything that would run in the onload of the form that displays when the db is launched (if there is one) and anything inside of the AutoExec module.

Comment: Yeah the project has multiple databases and the main function that starts the menu and prompts the error is roughly 1900 lines of code. I didn't write the code myself, what would the onload portion look like/start with?

Comment: `Sub Form_Load()` would be the sub routine opener.  Also look for anything that says `AutoExec`

Comment: Were you able to find either of those in your code?  The `Sub Form_Load()` would be in the VBA for the main menu.  The other would probably be inside of a general module.  In your project browser under modules.

Comment: I see `Sub OpenAFile()` but no `Sub Form_Load()` however, there are a ton of Subroutine blocks for various things including pieces that involve Excel. Here's an example:

Comment: Got it sorted out. Found where it wiped the references and commented it out. Thanks for your insight

Comment: Glad you were able to get it figured out.  Good luck with your project.  If you feel as though I was able to lead you to your answer please mark as answered.